# SharePoint 2013 My Site - Ask me about - Shows only if 6 or more than 6 keywords are added

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, mysite

In SharePoint 2013 My-Site if I edit my profile and add less than 6 keywords in the "Ask me about" section and save then added values are not displayed in the about me web part. If I add 6 or more than 6 keywords then it will display in the About me web part.

[image]

[image]

We have requirement to show even if the less than 6 keywords are entered in the Ask me about section.

Any settings in My Site where I can change the minimum value from 6 to 1?

Any help or Pointers will be appreciated.

-Vinayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved now.

I found that this was due to the news gator (Our my site using News gator controls) css which was overriding the `ms-askMeAbout-valuesFiveOrLess` class and making `display: none` if the items are less than 5.

Because of this the "Ask me about" section was not displaying.

To solve this I override the same class with `display:block !important` through

```
jQuery[$('.ms-askMeAbout-valuesFiveOrLess').attr('style','display:block !important')].
```

This resolved my issue.