# SharePoint 2013 Online - Ask me about- Hidden in Delve

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property

On my SharePoint Online Profile page (me.aspx in **Delve**) the **'Ask me about'** field is **hidden**. All other edited user properties show up, only this one is missing. The content of 'Ask me about' is crawled, indexed and visible in People Search results.

Any ideas what prevents it from being shown on the Profile page?

[Similar problem described here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118399/sharepoint-2013-my-site-ask-me-about-shows-only-if-6-or-more-than-6-keywords) --> If the problem lies on any **ms-askMeAbout-values** property in a css - how can I access & check it?

Comment: I am having the same issue - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '**Ask me about**' field has been hidden recently by Microsoft, making it reappear is not possible at this moment. They have other ideas for displaying peoples skills in future (see [here](https://blogs.office.com/2015/04/14/new-office-delve-people-experiences-in-office-365/)). For now, the ask me about field will still be crawled and is searchable in the search. You can manually create a new ask me about field if you need a visible field in the Delve page.